# Toggle eventListener using jQuery on() & off()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, addeventlistener

I have a JavaScript code snippet "Code Snippet 1 - that plays html videos loaded via Ajax on Users Touch Interaction" that uses the `on('touchstart')` jQuery method to attach event Listeners. I need to be able to Toggle the event Listeners on and off or remove and rebind them. The problem that I am having is the `on('touchstart')` method continues to call the function (plays all videos on page) each user interactions.

I need the event Listener to call the functions on the initial touch interaction, then disable, until ajax loads more content "Videos". After each Ajax Success I would like to rebind/re-add the event Listener, so the function works again.

**Code Snippet 1**

```
function videoEvents2() {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
        get: function() {
            return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'body', playVideoOnLowPower);
    $(document).on('touchstart', 'body', playVideoOnLowPower);

    function playVideoOnLowPower() {
        try {
            const videoElements = document.querySelectorAll("video");
            for (i = 0; i < videoElements.length; i++) {
                if (videoElements[i].playing) {
                    // video is already playing so do nothing
                    console.log('Playing');
                } else {
                    // video is not playing so play video now
                    videoElements[i].play();
                    console.log('Not Playing');
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried the following solutions with no success.

Attempt 1. Adding Boolean Attribute `{once: true}` to the eventlistener, but it did not provided the desired results. The Boolean attribute will only allow the functions to execute once.

Attempt 2.I used the `one()` instead of `on()` method for the eventlistener, however it provides the same results as `{once : true}`

Attempt 3. I've tried the `document.body.addEventListener` & `document.body.removeEventListener` method with the eventListeners reformatted like this "See Code Snippet Below this paragraph", however the "removeEventListener" method executes immediately instead of when the function is called.

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", playVideoOnLowPower, {
    once: true
});
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", playVideoOnLowPower, {
    once: true
});

function dsdvideoEvents3 {
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", playVideoOnLowPower, {
        once: true
    });
    document.body.removeEventListener("touchstart", playVideoOnLowPower, {
        once: true
    });
}
```

Attempt 4. I'm currently researching more Boolean Attributes, the Unbind & Rebind Methods, Delegation Methods, SetTimOut, and SetInterval methods, but I have not had any success.

Comment: please check the format of your question, it is currently in a format known as "dogs breakfast"

Comment: @JaromandaX Lol dogs breakfast! I'm new to this, ill get better HOPEFULLY . Essentially I need a way to remove the event listener after they have called the desired function. Then I need to rebind the event listeners after an Ajax call loads more elements so the functions can be called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a flag which hold the count of click for example here I have created `var clickCount = 0;` and increase it when you call `playVideoOnLowPower()` and reset it to 0 on `ajaxCall` success. Also check the `clickCount` value in `playVideoOnLowPower` method, if it is more than 0 return without doing anything otherwise execute your logic. See the following example.

```js
var clickCount = 0;

Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
  get: function() {
    return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
  }
});

document.body.addEventListener("click", playVideoOnLowPower);
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", playVideoOnLowPower);

function playVideoOnLowPower() {
  try {
    if (clickCount > 0) {
      return;
    }
    clickCount = 1;
    const videoElements = document.querySelectorAll("video");
    for (i = 0; i < videoElements.length; i++) {
      if (videoElements[i].playing) {
        // video is already playing so do nothing
        console.log('Playing');
      } else {
        // video is not playing so play video now
        videoElements[i].play();
        console.log('Not Playing');
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

$("#getVideo").off("click").on("click", function() {
  getVideo()
});

function getVideo() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://dummyjson.com/http/200/mov_bbb.mp4',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.status == 200) {
        var videoHtml = `<video width="400" controls>
                           <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/${data.message}" type="video/mp4">
                       </video>`;
      }
      $('#main2').append(videoHtml);
      videoEvents();
      clickCount = 0;
    }
  });

}

function videoEvents() {
  $("video").on('play', function() {
    $(this).prop('muted', false);
  });

  $("video").on('pause', function() {
    $(this).prop('muted', true);
  });

  $("video").on('ended', function() {
    $(this).prop('muted', true);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main2"></div>
<button id="getVideo">Add next video</button>
```

Comment: @AlberEinstein this did not work for me. The initial click plays the video, however after the ajax call the functions is not called again. In your example above this is exactly how I want it to work.

Comment: @DCMCODING show me your code. Or check each step properly. I have 4 new things in my code. In line 1 `var clickCount = 0;` , line 14 `if (clickCount > 0) {
      return;
    }` line 17 `clickCount = 1;` and in line 49  `clickCount = 0;`

Comment: @AlberEinstein I copied & pasted your code snippet that plays the video on touch, so that's an exact match. The only difference I can see is the ajax call. How do i show you my code in the comments?

Comment: After ajax call success you need to reset the count with `clickCount = 0;` that's all you need to do

Comment: @AlberEinstein that's already added. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.  This is what the ajax call looks like  $.ajax({
                url: 'https://randomurlhere.com'+step,
                success: function (data) { step++; $('main2').append(data); loading = false; dsdvideoEvents (); clickCount = 0; },
                dataType: 'html'
            });